# What is the correct way of mocking a user to test a login page with laravel and phpunit

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I currently have the following test, that basically creates a new user and makes sure the login can pass the test.

I'm using Laravel 5.6.

```
class LoginTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testLoginWorksWithValidCredentials()
    {

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = 'CMS';
        $user->email = 'test@test.com';
        $user->password = 'password';
        $user->save();

        $response = $this->postJson('/api/login', [
            'email' => 'test@test.com',
            'password' => 'password'
        ]);

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

Would this be the correct way of handling a test for the login, creating a user there and checking the login works? My assertions could of course be a little more specific, test for a specific response etc.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson 5.6 the latest.

Comment: It might be worth having a look at Model Factories https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/seeding#using-model-factories https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-5/episodes/9